# Adding time-stamp to image of youtube video

Tags: php, html, css, video, youtube

What I'm trying to do is get the exact look of the videos on the youtube homepage (image: [click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7Ttd.png)) **including** the time-stamp.

If you look in the source code, you'll find a link to the *image* of the video, however, I can't quite figure out how to get the time-stamp of the video and format it exactly how youtube has it simply from a youtube link (in this case: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IpBNr-oNT1g). I take it this would be done with PHP, but how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

http://itwigle.com/twig/Capturing_video_thumbnails_with_PHP

is this what you're looking for?